# Information Retrieval using Zipf's Law

Tags: dictionary, computer-science, data-mining, information-retrieval

How would you go about calculating the Dictionary Size of a list of stemmed texts using Zipf's Law?

Answer (score 0):

You don't calculate this.

You just *count*.